# convert int to natural number in ocaml

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

I am trying to write a function that converts integers to natural numbers in OCaml. Here is my code

```
type nat = Zero | Succ of nat 
let rec int_to_nat (x:int):nat option=
    if x<0 then
        None
    else if x=0 then
        Some Zero
    else
        Succ(int_to_nat (x-1));;
```

The compiler prompts "This variant expression is expected to have type nat option.The constructor Succ does not belong to type option" error. I don't understand what does it mean.

Comment: It means what it says. `Succ(...)` has type `nat`, but ti expects a `nat option`, like `Some (Succ ...)`, because that's what the other two branches of the `if` expression returns. They all need to return the same type, otherwise what would the type of the entire `if` expression be?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It expects a nat option. Here is what I changed

```
type nat = Zero | Succ of nat option
let rec int_to_nat (x:int):nat option=
    if x<0 then
        None
    else if x=0 then
        Some Zero
    else
        Some Succ(int_to_nat (x-1));;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the type to "Succ of nat option", because the resulting type wouldn't make sense. Instead, you could return a value with the appropriate type in your function:

```ml
type nat = Zero | Succ of nat

let rec int_to_nat (x:int) : (nat option) =
  if x < 0 then None else
  match x with
  | 0 -> None
  | _ -> let y = int_to_nat (x-1) in
    match y with
    | None -> None
    | Some z -> Some (Succ z);;
```

However, this will lead to stack overflow for large x. You can resolve this problem by making it tail-recursive:

```ml
type nat = Zero | Succ of nat

let int_to_nat (x:int) : (nat option) =
  if x < 0 then None else
  let rec int_to_nat' (x:int) (accum:nat) : (nat option) =
    match x with
    | 0 -> Some accum
    | _ -> int_to_nat' (x-1) (Succ accum)
  in int_to_nat' x Zero;;
```

Regarding tail-recursion, you might find the visualizations in this [blog post](http://siadat.github.io/blog/post/recursion-up-down) useful.